# Link error when I put template class with non-template classes in same cpp file - C++

Tags: c++, linker-errors, template-classes

I have a link-time problem when I include a templated and non-templated class in the same .cpp file.

I went through the C++ FAQ 35.13,35.14,35.15 and it doesn't solve the problem.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-class-defn-from-decl.html

I'm using Xcode 5 with clang.

Here's the example

#### barfoo.h

```
class bar{
public:
   void barfunc();
};

template <class T>
class foo{
public:
   void foofunc();
};
```

Here's the cpp file:

#### barfoo.cpp

```
void bar::barfunc(){...my code...}
template <class T>
void foo<T>::foofunc() {...my code...}
//I also put a instance of template class foo in the .cpp file
template class foo<int>;
//But is still generates the link error
```

The error is

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

But when I remove the bar class, the error disappears, can anyone tell me why it generates this error?

*Put the definition in the header file could solve the problem, but it may cause another problem that is code bloating, does anyone can give another solutions?*

Comment: The instantiation doesn't help. You can't put a definition that applies to all `T` in a different translation unit.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, so what should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: If you're defining it for all `T`, it needs to go in the header or somehow otherwise be included in the header (e.g., the header including the definition's file at the bottom).

Comment: In other words, put the definition of the method `foofunc` into the header as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the problem is I didn't instantiate the template class to the type I'm using in the code.

Here's the solutions to solve the template instantiate problem:

> 1. Put definition in header file so the compiler will have the instance information. (disadvantage, increase the loading and compiling time)
> 2. Instantiate all types that using in the code